# How do i define the key for this array?

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-3

Ok guys and gals,

I'm working with an amazing website of my client's that is written entirely in actionscript 3.0 with xml references.  The previous designer set up a mind-warping (for me) set of functions that is totally new to me, but probably normal practice for those familiar with c-based programming.  anyhow, there is a sub navigation menu that populates based on this array defenition... so i am facing a problem:

```
subnavData = new Array({"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true},
{"title":"CREATIVE DIRECTION", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showBranding, "childOf":0},
{"title":"SOCIAL INTERACTIVE", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showOnline, "childOf":0},
{"title":"LIVE EVENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showLiveEvents, "childOf":0},
{"title":"CONTENT STRATEGY", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showPerformance, "childOf":0},
{"title":"PROCESS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showProcess},
{"title":"CASE STUDIES", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showCaseStudies},
{"title":"CLIENTS", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showClients}
            );
```

the menu item on top has children, hence making it number 0 in the array... now the only way i have gotten this to work so far has been to set the "childOf" to '0', that is the string '0', not the value 0.  i am normally a php programmer, so i have experienced particular trouble with the inherent tendency for references to the 0 spot not to register from other functions.  so, this is primarily what i believe is the issue here, as the string declaration of '0' is not working for an iterative process in another function, as it is expecting a number and since 0 does not work for me, the menu won't display if i set it as that... see?

so what i am wondering is how i might start the ordering from 1 instead of 0 for this array.  i don't know how this is done when each instance in the array is contained in braces ( { } ).  in php, i would do something like this (hypothetically, if braced values were accepted by php):

`subnavData = array(1 => {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true}, etc...
);`

but when trying this in flash:

`subnavData = new Array(1 => {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true}, etc...
);`

it yields nothing.  please help.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although the syntax of your initial array is a little funky (convention is to not use string literals for field names. for example `{ title: 'mytitle'}`, not `{'title': 'mytitle'}` ), you do have a valid array of objects.

as mentioned before, in Actionscript, an `Array` cannot have custom keys; Array elements keys are just integers that point to the desired slot in the array. An `Object` is the data type that lets you use custom property names like `obj.myPropName` or `obj.title`.

**DON'T go skewing the array positioning**, you'll only confuse the next developer to touch the code! :)

From your snippet, I am guessing the the `childOf` property in your objects is supposed to reference an array index. If that is so, I bet you are running into issues checking for a valid `childOf` value. If you are iterating through the array checking each object for a valid `childOf` property like so:

```
for(var i:int = 0, l:int = subnavData.length; i < l; i++ )
{
    if( subnavData[i].childOf )
    {
        trace(i + ' is child of ' + subnavData[i].childOf)
    }
}
```

^traces nothing

then you will not get any matches. But clearly you have several entries with an `childOf = 0`. The boolean `if(subnavData[i].childOf)` check will fail if the value does not exist on the object OR if it is set to `0` ( `0 == false` ). you need to make a distinction between `0` and `undefined`. By changing your check statement to: `if( subnavData[i].childOf != undefined )` you can make that distinction.

ie)

```
for(var i:int = 0, l:int = subnavData.length; i < l; i++ )
{
    if( subnavData[i].childOf != undefined )
    {
        trace(i + ' is child of ' + subnavData[i].childOf)
    }
}
```

^ traces

```
1 is child of 0
2 is child of 0
3 is child of 0
4 is child of 0
```

I am taking a stab at what you are trying to accomplish, but think I see what might be tripping you up. Hopefully it helps :)

Comment: thank you very much... this seems to make the most sense.  i appreciate your time and will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do here.

But if you want to create an array that you can start counting from 1, you could make the 0 element be a blank array.

```
subnavData = new Array({}, {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true}, etc... );
```

But if you are just having trouble with accessing the elements in the multidimensional array, the standard way to do in in AS3 is:

```
something = subnavData[0][0];
someOtherThing = subnavData[0][1];
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also load the array like this, skipping 0:

```
var subnavData:Array = new Array();
subnavData[1] = {"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showServices, "hasChild":true};
subnavData[2] = {"title":"CREATIVE DIRECTION", "func":this.changeSlide, "param":this.showBranding, "childOf":0}
subnavData[3] = etc...
```

And by the way in flash {} creates an object, not an array. So you are making a 1 dimensional array with objects for values. So to access that data it would look like this:

```
subnavData[1].title;
// or you can do this
subnavData[1]['title']
```

Answer (score 0):

those braces within the array represent a new Object:

```
subnavData = new Array({"title":"OVERVIEW", "func":this.changeSlide});
```

could also be written like this (though usually wouldn't be since it's verbose):

```
var navObject:Object = new Object();
navObject["title"] = "OVERVIEW";
navObject["func"] = this.changeSlide;

subnavData = new Array(navObject);
```

it's actually more common to write object keys without quotes (though in some situations it can be useful or is required):

```
subnavData = new Array({title:"OVERVIEW", func:this.changeSlide});
```

or less terse with the dot operator:

```
var navObject:Object = new Object();
navObject.title = "OVERVIEW";
navObject.func = this.changeSlide;

subnavData = new Array(navObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Object class is the base class in AS3 , in some ways , similar to stdClass in PHP. You can create a new Object in two ways.

```
   var object:Object = new Object();
   var object:Object = {};
```

You can assign properties dynamically, like this:

```
    object.title = "OVERVIEW"; 
    // or this
    object = {title: "OVERVIEW" , ...}; // as in your example

    //you could also use the Array notation
    //but it is believed to be a lot slower
    object["title"] = "OVERVIEW";
```

You don't really need to mess with the Array, but you can easily change the childOf property if you're not comfortable with the 0 value. In your case , 0 is an integer, so when you iterate thru the Objects properties, the following should work:

```
    for each( var obj:Object in subnavData )
    {
        if( obj.childOf == 0 )
          //do whatever 

    }
```

But if you change the childOf property to "OVERVIEW" for instance, you could do this:

```
    for each( var obj:Object in subnavData )
    {
        if( obj.childOf == "OVERVIEW" )
         //do whatever             
    }
```

Practically change the childOf property to whatever you're comfortable with (provided of course that it's not being used anywhere else!!! the same goes for the Array indexing by the way) , although using 0 as an integer should work here. Can you post an example of the code you use when you iterate thru the Array?